# How to customize a linux kernel: modify CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I would like to set `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=n` and recompile my kernel in order to try out what @Oliv suggested in the comments of [my question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597068/modify-kernel-parameters-mmap-operation-not-permitted-eperm).

I am following the [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) tutorial on the ubuntu wiki:

```
$ git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git
$ cd ubuntu-bionic/
$ chmod a+x debian/rules
$ chmod a+x debian/scripts/*
$ chmod a+x debian/scripts/misc/*
$ fakeroot debian/rules clean
$ sudo fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
dh_testdir;
/bin/bash -e debian/scripts/misc/kernelconfig editconfigs
Do you want to edit config: amd64/config.flavour.generic? [Y/n] Y
```

and I face the following menu:
[image]

I have searched arround in the hope of finding the variable that I need to change (`CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`), but I didn't find it.

Most of the resources that I find on the internet elaborate on compiling/building the kernel, but I didn't find anything on actually making specific changes.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT 1:**

A file:

```
./build/.config
```

is created when `sudo fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` is aborted.

```
$ cat ./build/.config | grep CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM
```

returns

```
CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y
CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y
```

I set these variables to n and ran

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
```

which ended in an error:

```
/bin/bash: gawk: command not found
debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:123: recipe for target 'install-generic' failed
make: *** [install-generic] Error 127
```

**EDIT 2:**

Now I am following [a different tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/in-depth-howto-on-linux-kernel-configuration) and @Oliv's advice:

- I installed `gawk`
- I ran `make menuconfig` to generate a file called `.config` at the root of the git repository.
- I set `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` from `=y` to `=n`
- I ran `make menuconfig` again.
- `cat .config | grep CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` returns `# CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM is not set`
- Now I am running `make && make modules_install && make install` as root.

I will report any further progress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it worked out.

Here is a general "recipe" for people who want to modify their kernel

- Use `ll /proc/ | grep conf` and `ll /boot/ | grep conf` to locate your config file.
- Check how the variable of interest is configured using `path_to_config | grep variable_of_interest` or unzip it if necessary: `path_to_config.gz | gunzip | grep variable_of_interest`

If you want to change the value of one of these variables you need to do the following:

- Clone the git repository that contains your kernel. I used:

  `git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git`

  replace `bionic` with the code name of your operating system.
- Install software:

  `sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r) && sudo apt-get install gawk`
- `cd ubuntu-bionic/` again replace bionic with the codename of your OS.
- Make the following files executable:

  `chmod a+x debian/rules
  chmod a+x debian/scripts/*
  chmod a+x debian/scripts/misc/*`
- Run `fakeroot debian/rules clean`
- Copy your current configurations into the root of the git repository:

  `cp path_to_config ./.config`
- Configure `.config` according to your needs. I recommend setting `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=n` and `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4=n` in order to reduce the compilation time and in order to avoid using up so much disk space during compilation.
- Run:

  `sudo su
   make menuconfig
   make && make modules_install && make install`

Now be patient...

In my case `path_to_config | grep variable_of_interest` still returned the old configuration uppon completion of the above steps, but the changes had been made to the kernel and it was working as required.